# Line Art Modifier - Light Contour Issue

Tags: rendering, modifiers, lighting, grease-pencil, lineart

Alright so I'm doing some work with the line art modifier, but whenever I use the Light contour effect it results in a choppy jagged line seemingly based on the model's geometry.[image: Result I keep getting]

According to Blender's Official update notes, it appears like it would work as intended, but It's not working for me even on a simple sphere.[image: Blender update log]

This is the desired result:
[image]

Comment: Hi Marux. After the Line Art modifier add Smooth modifier with 5-7 Repeats and Keep Shape turned on. You should probably need to Move the Plane object outside of the Collection and use another Grease pencil on it, because the smoothing of its contours won't look very good.

Comment: Already tried that, It jacks up a lot of other lines, especially sharp edges and corners. It also doesn't align with where the line is SUPPOSED to be, so that's a no-go.

Comment: I just tried it and get the same problem from a minimal setup.
Interestingly, if you look at the scene from a different angle than the camera, the outline of the sphere also looks jagged like the light contour – the jagged pattern just comes together from the camera's perspective to look smooth. Since the light contour seems to be based on a 'virtual camera' looking at the sphere from the position of the light, I guess it makes sense it also gets that jagged pattern when not looking from the light's position? (Still don't know if bug or some obscure setting.)

Comment: Interestingly, the outline of the sphere also being jagged when looking at it from the side is not new (I also get it in 3.2). However, I can't find anyone mentioning it online or any information on how to smooth that one out, either. But that makes it seem like there should be a setting for it somewhere and it is not a (recent) bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result seem to be as it should be. If you take a look at the demo file *0_cast_shadow.blend* provided in [LineArt: Shadow Functionality. - Blender Archive - developer.blender.org](https://archive.blender.org/developer/D15109) by its developer:

[image]

The developer used a combination of Simplify and Smooth modifiers to refine the shape of the contour lines.

Without it, it looks like this:

[image]

The mesh objects also have a high mesh density using Subdivision modifiers to help negate the effect. Otherwise, it looks like this:

[image]

---

I reproduces your scene:

[image]

I also created two line layers and two lineart modifiers to handle the light contour and the "rest" of the lines individually:

[image]

To make this look good:

1. Select the sphere and add a subdivision modifier level 3 (you can press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>, or add one manually in the *Properties Editor* > *Modifiers tab*)
   [image]
2. Add a Simplify modifier (make it target the light contour modifier if you made one) and play with the Length and Angle settings
   [image]
3. Add a Smooth modifier (make it target the light contour modifier if you made one) and play with the Iteration settings
   [image]

I couldn't find a way to simplify specifically the contour over the area of the sphere where the topology pinches:
[image]

So I advise rotating that sphere to "hide" that part, or use an icosphere that has a uniform topology:
[image]

Comment: Weird that the official blend file for this effect is still using what seems to a be a really roundabout and unintuitive "fix". Thanks for the help though!

Comment: It's an in-development system, there are lots of roundabouts right now.